# Calling images from firebase storage - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, firebase-storage

**Hello everyone!**

I am **trying** to make a custom hook that can be used to call images from firebase storage. The input into the function is from a DATA.js file that contains JSON. e.g useImageSource(item.photo) - item.photo would be equal to "lowerbody/forward-legswing" (thats the file structure in my firebase storage to that workout image). Hopefully it makes more sense when I show you my code! ha!

[image: Error screenshot]

**useImageSource**

Below is an example of the custom hook I made for this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import firebase from "@react-native-firebase/app";
import "@react-native-firebase/storage";
import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";

import { getIllustration, Images } from "@flexeee:assets/images/Images";

export default function useImageSource(image, defaultImage) {
  const storage = firebase.storage();
  const [imageSource, setImageSource] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getImageSource() {
      try {
        const url = await storage.ref(`images/${image}.png`).getDownloadURL();
        setImageSource({
          uri: url,
          priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        setImageSource(defaultImage ?? Images.upperBody);
      }
    }

    getImageSource();
  }, [image, defaultImage, storage]);

  return imageSource;
}
```

**SubCategories**

So here is an example of somewhere where I tried to implement this useImageSource hook I made:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
} from "react-native";
import { Fontisto } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import ReactNativeHapticFeedback from "react-native-haptic-feedback";
import useImageSource from "@flexeee:common/utils/hooks/useImageSource";

import { Colors } from "@flexeee:common/theme/Colors";
import { Fonts } from "@flexeee:common/theme/Sizes";
import { Images } from "@flexeee:assets/images/Images";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const options = {
  enableVibrateFallback: true,
  ignoreAndroidSystemSettings: false,
};

export default function SubCategories({ navigation, workouts, category }) {
  
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const imageSrc = useImageSource(item.photo, Images.upperBody);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginBottom: 10 * 2 }}
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate("DetailStack", {
            screen: "WorkoutDetails",
            params: { item: item },
          }) & ReactNativeHapticFeedback.trigger("impactLight", options)
        }
      >
        {/* Image */}
        <View style={styles.workoutImageContainer}>
          {item.isLocked ? (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.black, borderRadius: 10 }}>
              <Image
                source={imageSrc}
                resizeMode="cover"
                style={styles.workoutImage}
                opacity={0.75}
              />
            </View>
          ) : (
            <Image
              source={imageSrc}
              resizeMode="cover"
              style={styles.workoutImage}
            />
          )}
          <View style={styles.durationContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.duration}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        {item.isLocked && (
          <View style={styles.lockContainer}>
            <Fontisto name="locked" size={28} color={Colors.white} />
          </View>
        )}
        <View style={styles.subtitleContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.headingContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>{category.name}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("DetailStack", {
              screen: "WorkoutList",
              params: { category: category, workouts: workouts },
            }) & ReactNativeHapticFeedback.trigger("impactLight", options)
          }
        >
          <Text style={styles.viewOption}>View all</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={workouts}
        horizontal
        keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        contentContainerStyle={{}}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**DATA.js**

Here is some context on my data (an example)

```
export const workoutData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Lower-body warm up",
    rating: 4.8,
    categories: [1],
    isLocked: false,
    description: `Ah, the infamous 'leg day.' Sometimes it's a struggle to even make it to the gym when you're planning to train your lower body, let alone spend time warming up before the often dreaded workout. But not only can avoiding a warm-up increase your risk of injury, it can also hinder your performance. This holds especially true when you walk into the gym after a night of sleep or a long day of sitting at a desk. A good warm-up will raise your body temperature, improve mobility and groove proper movement patterns. Some people require more mobility, while others require more stability. Regardless of your needs, there are several warm-up exercises that can prepare you for almost any type of lower-body exercise.\n \nTip: Spend five minutes on a foam roller before your warm-up to better prepare your muscles.`,
    photo: "lowerbody/deep-squat",
    duration: `5 mins`,
    trainer: {
      avatar: "lowerbody/deep-squat",
      name: "Amy",
    },
    workout: [
      {
        exerciseId: 1,
        name: "Forward Leg Swing (left)",
        photo: "lowerbody/forward-legswing",
        description:
          "Stand straight with your feet hip-width apart and hold onto a wall. Keeping one leg stationary, slowly swing the opposite leg forward and backward in a single smooth movement.",
        muscle: "Hip flexors, hamstrings, quadriceps, glutes & calves",
        duration: 30,
      },
      {
        exerciseId: 2,
        name: "Forward Leg Swing (right)",
        photo: "lowerbody/forward-legswing",
        description:
          "Stand straight with your feet hip-width apart and hold onto a wall. Keeping one leg stationary, slowly swing the opposite leg forward and backward in a single smooth movement.",
        muscle: "Hip flexors, hamstrings, quadriceps, glutes & calves",
        duration: 30,
      },
```

**Firebase storage file structure**

[image]

Hopefully that is enough information to help me solve this problem? If not I am happy to provide more details - a note to make is that before this when I called my files locally in my DATA.js file **was working**. Just need some ideas or assistance on why this isn't working!

**Thank you** for your time and I look forward to hearing a response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it seems my issue here was that I wasn't returning anything in render. I have to return another component which I called {company}Image that returned fast image in render which called FastImage and had image as a prop.

Hope this is useful to anyone who reads this!